# How to make half circle in the frame?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make half circle in the layout just like below Image. How to make that type of layout.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and why is it not working. Please do not ask for someone to just do it for you.

Comment: Please mention what have you tried and searched to complete it. As you can also do this by simply using image so what is you requirement, clearly mention that.

Comment: Thanks everyone ,I will use image for circle

Comment: You can simply use an image for your background (or, even better, a 9 patch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to make half circle in the frame ?

You can use `9-patch` Image for this requirement .

> 9 Patch images are stretchable, repeatable images reduced to their
>   smallest size.the image won't stretch and loose proportions in
>   different screen sizes.

Go Through **[Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/draw9patch.html)**

Comment: Another nice tutorial is found [here](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/).